# Magento-2.2.4 order confirmation mail not sent to logged user

Tags: email, order-email, magento2.2.4

Order confirmation mail not sending only to logged in user. Guest user receiving order mail. Send mail function in order detail section from admin also not sending mail.

Comment: check server and magento logs

Comment: @kunj Already checked but not found related to this issue.